# Liferay override document library web

Tags: liferay, osgi-bundle, gogo-shell

Hi guys I developed a module to override jsp of a document library, so with `blade deploy` command in localhost all run perfect, document library shows my custom jsp, but when I deploy this jar module to a remote web server through gogo or web UI (liferay apps manager) and status show equals as in localhost (Status: Resolved) but mi custom jsp doesn't show.

Comment: I tried `refresh host fragment` via `gogo comands` restart server, clean tomcat, but nothing change...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site